# Does gcp firestore in datastore mode support OR query?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Consider following data in GCP datastore:

```
users: [
{name: 'jane', email: 'jane@somesite.com', user_id: 1},
{name: 'jacob', email: 'jacob@somesite.com', user_id: 2},
{name: 'john', email: 'john@sometime.com', user_id: 3}
]

relations: [
{user1_id: 1, user2_id: 2, relation_name: "spouse"},
{user1_id: 2, user2_id: 3, relation_name: "father_son"}
]
```

I want to fetch all relations for user jacob for that I need to query for jacob's ID in two columns that is `user1_id` & `user2_id` using some sort of `OR` logic while running datastore query but I am unable to find any document with the required example to make `OR` query.

Is this possible in one query else I will have to make two separate query one with column `user1_id` and other user `user2_id`.

I am using firestore in datastore mode and I am using node js client library to fetch result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP Firestore in datastore mode does not natively support 'OR' operator but some client libraries add the support for 'OR' operator. Check restriction on queries for more details.